# How to create a multiprocessing queue by key in Python3

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Is there a way to get in Python3 what in C is:

```
int msgget(key_t key, int flags);
```

I have to create a game that has two players and the communication is done by message passing.

For this purpose I can create an object multiprocessing.Queue() but I can't seem to find a way to pass this object from player 1 to player 2. Each player is running in its own terminal so they are not in a parent-child relation.

To solve this I would need something like the above function in C that can get a Queue object based on some key or id. Does any simple way of sharing this object between two processes running in different terminal exist?

Comment: Take a look at [msgq](https://github.com/sral/msgq): System V IPC Message Queue Python Extension Module.

Comment: That would solve it, but I would prefer not to use 3rd party libs. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two processes cannot access objects in each other's memory, so they will have to communicate over some kind of connection - most likely a socket connection. A message queue such as the one recommended as a comment, or perhaps ZeroMQ, is perfect for that job, and not hard to set up. Have a look at http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:all.

Allthough using a messaging protocol or messaging service that can do many things may seem like a lot of work and overhead in such cases, it's actually a really simple and intuitive way to handle this.